# IBM Watson Assistant: How to deal with numbers in user examples/intents?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

We use IBM Watson Assistant with German language. Therefore, we're not able to use annotations within intents since its only available for English language.

We have an intent called offer which has examples as:

- offer **postalcode**
- offers for **postalcode**
- company offer for    district **postalcode**
- Tablet offer for **postalcode**

etc.

How can I find a solution so that e.g "offer 4082" triggers the right answer without using numbers within the user examples in intents.

Same actually goes for a variety of intents including other numbers, locations, etc.

Comment: It seems that you are using dialog skill. Have you tried the action skill?

Comment: Hi Henrik,

thats right, unfortunately we are not on the plus plan so theres no action skill for us. 

But we consider on going there. What would be the difference between these two regarding my question?

Comment: Action skill is independent of the service plan. It seems that your WA instance is existing for a while when the default were dialog skills and the (now) "classic experience". You could switch. There are also two sets of documentations.

Comment: Hi Henrik, unfortunately thats not my case. If i want to create a new skill, theres literally a "plus"-sign next to the action and search skill. I doesnt even allow me to continue. Im only able to try the plus plan.

Comment: AFAIK the Lite plan supports one skill, either action or dialog. You would need to delete the existing skill (or the WA instance and recreate it)

Comment: Hi Henrik, were on the standard plan and we had 6 dialog skills